# Natural Density of Numbers Divisible by a Power of a Prime

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

I am trying to understand natural density and came across the claim (in these [notes](https://sites.math.washington.edu/%7Econroy/WXML/integerSequenceNoise/density/densityExamples.pdf)) that for any prime $p$ and positive integer $k$, the density of integers that are exactly divisible by $p^k$
is:
$$\frac{1}{p^k}-\frac{1}{p^{k+1}}$$

However, I also know that if $m$ is a positive integer, $B$ a set of residue classes modulo $m$, and $S$ the set of all positive integers that are congruent to elements of $B$, then
$$d(S) = \frac{|B|}{m}$$ where $d(S)$ is the natural density of S. (For example, the set of integers congruent to 1, 4 or 7 modulo 8 has natural density $\tfrac{3}{8}$).

From the formula above, I would think that the density of integers exactly divisible by $p^k$ is simply $\tfrac{1}{p^k}$ since we are looking for all integers congruent to zero modulo $p^k$. I do not understand where the $-\tfrac{1}{p^{k+1}}$ of the claim above comes from.

I also know about the fact that natural density is additive such that $d(S_1 \cup S_2) = d(S_1)+d(S_2)$, but I do not see where that is needed here, nor where it would lead to the result that the density of integers that are exactly divisible by $p^k$ is
$\tfrac{1}{p^k}-\tfrac{1}{p^{k+1}}$.

Am I missing some key way to express the set of integers divisible by $p^k$ as a union of sets?

Comment: $27$ is divisible by $3^2$ but not exactly $3^2$ because $27=3^3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for that subtraction is that the density of integers that are divisible by $p^k,p^{k+1},p^{k+2},\dots$ is $1/p^k$, so the density of integers that are exactly divisible by $p^k$ is the density of integers that are divisible by $p^k,p^{k+1},p^{k+2},\dots$ minus the density of integers that are divisible by $p^{k+1},p^{k+2},p^{k+3},\dots$.

Therefore, the desired density should be $1/p^k-1/p^{k+1}$.

Comment: So, if I understand you correctly, when we say "integers exactly divisible by $p^k$" we mean "integers $n$ such that $k$ is the highest power of $p$ which divides $n$"?

Comment: I think this is the only way to explain that subtraction.